# provisioning profile problem?

Tags: iphone

i am new to creating provisioning profile.can i use same provisioning profile for all applications(except using *, we can install one app at a time)?for example if i go bundle identifier and give my comapanyname only as com.mycompanyname(apple id).${PRODUCT_NAME:identifier},and also i set my certifate,after that
will my application run in device?(**without creating provisioning file for each application**),i have seen like this in  my friend system,how is it possible?any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same provisioning profile for all applications certainly if you are willing to install the application on your device  only and your device's udid is included in the provisioning profile.

**EDIT:** For creating provisioning profiles see this [blog post](http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/content/howto-iphone-application-development-environment)

It would be better if u clarify the error u are getting in using the same profile.

Thanks,
Madhup

Comment: you did not mention how to create that provisioning profile(which consists device id),how to name for that provisioning profile? can you please?

Comment: @senthilmuthu : You need to follow this http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/content/howto-iphone-application-development-environment

Comment: hi, the tutorial give to use to create app id com.companyname.*...but
i asked not to use * symbol and to run app in device when i change bundle identifier(one provisioning profile)